# KMM app build fails when adding Firebase dependency

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

Unable to add gitlive version of Firebase to a KMM app.
https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk

I'd like to add Firebase to my KMM app, but am running into an issue where I am unable to successfully add any of the dependencies. I've added the dep to the commonMain target and synced gradle; the Android app builds successfully, the iOS build fails, and I am unable to import the dep in commonMain.
Note: I have been able to add other, non-Firebase, dependencies.

I am very new to KMM and any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated - Thank you!

Here is an example project that demonstrates the issue:
https://github.com/iamthearm/FirebaseKMMTest

This seems to be the relevant bit of the iOS build output

```
> Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosX64 FAILED
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld invocation reported errors

The /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld: framework not found FirebaseAuth
error: Compilation finished with errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosX64'.
> Compilation finished with errors

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Edit:
I have also tried the framework version of the KMM framework and also tried installing Firebase through cocoapods directly with no luck. The example project is the standard framework version.

Comment: "SDK achieves this by binding to the respective official Firebase SDK for each supported platform." They're using cocoapods plugin to work with iOS SDK, so I guess you also have to use cocoapods integration to make it work. You can also create an issue in the repository - at least they could've updated the doc clarifying this.

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thank you, but I have tried the cocoapods KMM framework version and also tried adding the missing frameworks to the pods file (then pod install/pod update/etc). No dice. You're right, though, I do believe this is a bug but was hopeful on here 